# Conflict in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Right so I've got a bit of jQuery that exposes a couple of divs on the right hand side of my page. Here's the test link that works:

[TEST](http://quotesin.co.uk/testslide.html)

Now when I integrate that into my site it doesn't work at all and I can't find the glitch. I've just copied the entire page from the test into my layout page as, no matter what order I put it in it doesn't work. Can anyone identify the bug? I'm sure I'm doing something wrong that is so simple but need a bit of professional guidance. Here's the non-working link:

[SITE](http://www.quotesin.co.uk)

Comment: Do you get any errors in your browser's console? (Also, neither of your hyperlinks works.)

Comment: Your links are broken..

Comment: always check the console for errors!

Comment: @mrmason I upvoted your question because I'm not convinced it deserved 2 downvotes. I felt you gave us evidence that you had made an effort to find a solution yourself with "no matter what order I put it in it" and it was an interesting challenge for me.

Comment: @DavidHyogo Thanks very much, really appreciate that. I have been scratching my head on it to be honest i've been tapping away for an hour now, and i may be under guessing it there. Just trying to find the route of this error now... It seems to be hiding. Thanks Again

Comment: @mrmason Hope this isn't too obvious, but you said offer guidance.  You need to take baby steps when debugging.  e.g. Comment everything out in the relevant chunk of code and add code back line by line until your debugging tool (I favour Firebug) points out an error.  Send variables to the console and check they contain the value you expect etc. Use an IDE that highlights syntax errors (My favourite is Aptana)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'onEnd' 

sublimevideo.ready(function() {
      sublimevideo.onEnd(function(sv) {
        sublimevideo.stop();
      });
    });
```

That is where your error is, `.onEnd()` is not jQuery.

Comment: +1 for finding further error despite presence of SyntaxError

Answer (score 1):

Syntax error bro :)

```
Czas: 04.07.2013 14:00:21
Błąd: SyntaxError: syntax error
Plik źródłowy: http://www.quotesin.co.uk/index.php
Wiersz: 76, Kolumna: 51
Kod źródłowy:
                   jQuery('#userNav').show('slide',,1000);
```

Comment: The question is, why OP's jQuery plugin doesn't work - it won't work with syntax error - isn't that obvious?

Comment: you didn't gave him the solution instead you told him the error!

Comment: yikes, didnt think it would get this heated, bad days always get worse :) So this syntax is causing {direction:'right'} to not function :/ hmmmmm

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui I don't agree.  mrmason asked for guidance and asked if anyone could identify the bug.  That's what both ElmoVanKielmo and I did, unfortunately at the same time.  Pointing out the syntax and suggesting debugging tools constitute guidance and help in identifying the bug.

Comment: @mrmason, syntax error stops the whole javascript. It's like a dead end.

Answer (score 1):

I opened the SITE link in Firefox with Firebug running and found this syntax error:

```
jQuery('#userNav').show('slide',,1000);
```

Firebug is pointing to the second comma after slide on line 84.

Are you using Firebug or some other developer's tool such as the ones available in Chrome or Safari to do your debugging?

Comment: +1 for finding the killer of js interpreter - you used Firebug and I used the console.

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo Thanks, but you found the same syntax error.

Comment: I know @DavidHyogo but this is the main issue in my opinion.